# How to embed some tableViews with different data in a collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, swift5

Right now all four tableViews in collectionView are showing the data from data1 array. How do I display data1 in the first collectionViewCell and data2 in the second one and so on? I'm new to this so please help.

Current code in ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let data1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    let data2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"]
    let data3 = ["I", "J", "K", "L"]
    let data4 = ["M", "N", "O", "P"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mealCellID", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
           layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data1.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dishCellID")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = data1[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

}
```

And CollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dishCellID")!
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your functions and vars  as i have done, currently as you are doing with data1, data2,data3 etc...  you can't  achieve the required functionality.

```
let dataSource = [["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    ,["E", "F", "G", "H"],
    ["I", "J", "K", "L"],
    ["M", "N", "O", "P"]]

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mealCellID", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.dataSource = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self

        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
```

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
           layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dishCellID")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = cell?.dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}



    import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var dataSource = [String]()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dishCellID")!
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: I got two errors: first one is in viewController. What should I return for the numberOfRowsInSection? The other one is is also in viewController. It says "value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'dataSource'".